# How to make jQuery animate work only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I tried making an animation that if the user clicks next and it reaches to an image that is hidden, the jQuery animation will take effect to display the next batch of images. Like for example if I have six images and the first three images are displayed, if the user clicks for the fourth time, it will now scroll to view the last three images. Now, I only want to use the animation once. The problem is, it will still continue to animate every time I click the button. How to only use the animation once?

Here is the script:

```
next.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter + 1) % numImages];
  counter++;
  if(counter == 5) {
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
    document.getElementById('prev').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '1';
  }
  if(counter == 2) {
    $(function() {
      $('#next').on('click', function () {
        $('#imageList').stop().animate({left : '-=285px'}, 1000);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Set a global variable to work as a Boolean switch and make it a conditional check for the animation. After the first time it runs through the animation, flip the Boolean switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var animation = true;

next.onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter + 1) % numImages];
    counter++;

    if (counter == 5) {
        document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
        document.getElementById('prev').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '1';
    }

    if (counter == 2) {
        $(function() {
                $('#next').on('click', function() {
                        if (animation) {
                            animation = false;
                            $('#imageList').stop().animate({
                                left: '-=285px'
                            }, 1000, function() {
                                animation = true;
                            }););
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

I have set up a global boolean called ***animation*** which is set to true, then on click, check if ***animation*** is true, if so set it to false and play animation, the `.animation()` has also a callback function which specifies when animation has been completed once completed set the ***animation*** variable back to true so next click can play the animation again if needed, if you don't want it to be playable again, just remove the variable and/or whole callback function.

[.animation() docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: hi! if you are interested, checkout my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131984/jquery-scrolling-thumbnail-images-animation-not-working-properly. it is related to the solution you gave me and i am having problems with making the prev button work.

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly improve your event registration:

```
$(next).one('click', function(){

    document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter + 1) % numImages];
    counter++;

    if(counter == 5){
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
    document.getElementById('prev').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '1';
  }

  if(counter == 2){
  $(function () {
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
     $('#imageList').stop().animate({left : '-=285px'}, 1000);
     });
  });
 }

})
```