# Jquery scrolling thumbnail images animation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

This is related to the previous question that i posted [How to make jQuery animate work only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119049/how-to-make-jquery-animate-work-only-once). Now, I have successfully added the solution provided and it seems to be working at first. So i tried clicking the next button, and then if it reaches the 3rd click, the jquery scrolling animation will take effect. But when i tried to click the prev button, the jquery animation is not working. Its suppose to go back to the previous images. Kindly help me on solving this one.

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Image1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Image2.js"></script>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <img id="defaultPic" src="microsoftLogo1.jpg" /><br/>
    <button id= "prev" class="portfolioNavigation">Previous</button>
    <div id="container">
       <ul id="imageList">  
            <li><img id="subPic1" src="microsoftLogo1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic2" src="microsoftLogo2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic3" src="microsoftLogo3.gif" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic4" src="microsoftLogo4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic5" src="microsoftLogo5.png" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic6" src="microsoftLogo6.png" /></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
    <button id= "next" class="portfolioNavigation">Next</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var animation = true;
    var counter = 0;
    var srcArray = ["microsoftLogo1.jpg", "microsoftLogo2.jpg", 
     "microsoftLogo3.gif", "microsoftLogo4.jpg", "microsoftLogo5.png", 
     "microsoftLogo6.png"];
    var numImages = srcArray.length;

    if(counter == 0){
       document.getElementById('prev').disabled = 'true';
        document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '0.5';
    }

   prev.onclick = function(){

     document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter - 1) % 
    numImages];
     counter--;

     if(counter == 0){
       document.getElementById('prev').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '0.5';
       document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
     }

       if(counter == 2){
       $(function() {
            $('#prev').on('click', function() {
                    if (animation) {

                        $('#imageList').stop().animate({
                            left: '+=285px'
                        }, 1000, function() {
                           animation = false;
                        });
                }
            });
       });
      }
    };

next.onclick = function() {

document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter + 1) % 
numImages];
counter++;

if (counter == 5) {
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
}

if (counter == 2) {
    document.getElementById('prev').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '1';
    $(function() {
            $('#next').on('click', function() {
                    if (animation) {

                        $('#imageList').stop().animate({
                            left: '-=285px'
                        }, 1000, function() {
                            animation = false;
                        });
                }
            });
    });
 }
 };


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you consider making a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with all your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have on variable animate which you're trying to control two separate animations with, just set up another variable and use it the same way as the first one...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Image1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Image2.js"></script>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <img id="defaultPic" src="microsoftLogo1.jpg" /><br/>
    <button id= "prev" class="portfolioNavigation">Previous</button>
    <div id="container">
       <ul id="imageList">  
            <li><img id="subPic1" src="microsoftLogo1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic2" src="microsoftLogo2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic3" src="microsoftLogo3.gif" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic4" src="microsoftLogo4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic5" src="microsoftLogo5.png" /></li>
            <li><img id="subPic6" src="microsoftLogo6.png" /></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
    <button id= "next" class="portfolioNavigation">Next</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var animation = true;
    var backAnimation = true;
    var counter = 0;
    var srcArray = ["microsoftLogo1.jpg", "microsoftLogo2.jpg", 
     "microsoftLogo3.gif", "microsoftLogo4.jpg", "microsoftLogo5.png", 
     "microsoftLogo6.png"];
    var numImages = srcArray.length;

    if(counter == 0){
       document.getElementById('prev').disabled = 'true';
        document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '0.5';
    }

   prev.onclick = function(){

     document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter - 1) % 
    numImages];
     counter--;

     if(counter == 0){
       document.getElementById('prev').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '0.5';
       document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
     }

       if(counter == 2){
       $(function() {
            $('#prev').on('click', function() {
                    if (backAnimation) {

                        $('#imageList').stop().animate({
                            left: '+=285px'
                        }, 1000, function() {
                           backAnimation = false;
                        });
                }
            });
       });
      }
    };

next.onclick = function() {

document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = srcArray[(counter + 1) % 
numImages];
counter++;

if (counter == 5) {
    document.getElementById('next').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('next').style.opacity = '0.5';
}

if (counter == 2) {
    document.getElementById('prev').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('prev').style.opacity = '1';
    $(function() {
            $('#next').on('click', function() {
                    if (animation) {

                        $('#imageList').stop().animate({
                            left: '-=285px'
                        }, 1000, function() {
                            animation = false;
                        });
                }
            });
    });
 }
 };


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've also noticed something weird in the if(counter == 2) statement in the next. For the first time the counter is incrementing, if the counter is 2 == 2, it is not executing the animation. But if the counter is 3 == 2, the animation is executed, which is really weird.

Comment: Watch where you increment/decrement the counter.